# Avoid multiple page redirects about from HTTP to HTTPS and from non-www HTTPS to with-www HTTPS

Tags: google-pagespeed

Humbly, In Google PageSpeed Insights test I got 95 score for mobile and 95 score for desktop with pretty much just one error:

> Avoid multiple page redirects

The first entry of the error is about *HTTP to HTTPS* redirects and the second entry of the error is about *non-www HTTPS to with-www HTTPS* redirects.

The first entry is **weird** because its Google themselves who passionately promote HTTP to HTTPS usage, so why would they give me an error for doing so?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that you're redirecting, but that you're doing so more than once.

Rebuild your redirect to fix the URL just the once. For example, if your desired URL is https://www.example.com/ then just redirect to that. Don't redirect from http to https and then non-www to www.

### Update based on comment by the OP

In case the comment would get deleted:

> My entire question here is false, I was confused; there is no entry about non-www HTTPS to do-www HTTPS ; there is a second entry `/index.php?title=` (the first is about http to https).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification as in the first sentence in your answer; you said `Don't redirect from http to https and then non-www to www.`; well, I must do so for CloudFloure to protect from possible DDoSs... So, might it be that I am bound to suffer from this more-than-one-redirecting situation? I could solve it by point my DNS nameservers to CloudFlare directly without the mediation of my hosting provider but than I will lose the special benefits of the CloudFlare mediation of my hosting provider.

Comment: My entire question here is false, I was confused; there is no entry about non-www HTTPS to do-www HTTPS ; there is a second entry `/index.php?title=` (the first is about http to https).

Comment: Your answer is correct in principle but is referring to a wrong case from my end; I am sorry for that; you might want to update the answer about the data I sufficed in comment, in case the comments gets deleted.

Comment: I have suggested that edit in case it a notification will not appear to you: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69802

Comment: It's not really helpful to the site to change the question and the answer, after it's been accepted. If the question was substantially wrong, ask another.